# CodeIgniter - print custom values in request header

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

How can I print the values set in the header of a received request using CodeIgniter?

I tried `print_r($_SERVER);` which doesn't help me. I'm hoping there's a different way using CI.

Comment: use CI's Input class: $this->input->request_headers(); (or apache_request_headers() if available).

Comment: Read [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

Comment: @JoséTrindade exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Here is new docs: [CI3](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html), [CI2](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/input.html).

Comment: how i set value in CI at time of form submit to get value in  $this->input->request_headers();

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply use,

`$this->input->request_headers();`

Comment: how i set value in CI at time of form submit to get value in $this->input->request_headers();

Comment: @sunil you can't. CI is for the back end of your application and requests (including the request header) are created from the front end (usually via AJAX). Ask a new question if you need help.

Comment: Thanks @john , yes its working with ajax , but as you said in form it can't work , so thereis nothing to do with curl or something else if i wish o not use jquery ajax

Comment: what is used in CI v4? I have tried headers, header and getHeaderLine to get customer header but didn't get response

Comment: get specific value  $this->input->request_headers()['Host']

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending values from form submit,

```
$_REQUEST will help you

or

    $this->input->post();
    $this->input->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but `$this->input->request_headers(); ` was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To receive all values from the request header

```
$valuesInHeader = $this->input->request_headers();
```

To get specific value from request header

```
$hostValueInHeader = $this->input->request_headers()['Host'];
//"Host" is a key of a value, you can use your required key.
```